# In Scala 2.10, how do you create a ClassTag given a TypeTag

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I'd like to define a function that returns an Array, and I have a TypeTag. Can I generate the required ClassTag?

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def fun[X: TypeTag]: Array[X] = Array.ofDim[X](10)
<console>:11: error: No ClassTag available for X
       def fun[X: TypeTag]: Array[X] = Array.ofDim[X](10)
```

Or is it necessary to provide implicit evidence of the ClassTag:

```
scala> import reflect.ClassTag
import reflect.ClassTag

scala> def fun[X: ClassTag: TypeTag]: Array[X] = Array.ofDim[X](10)(implicitly[ClassTag[X]])
fun: [X](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[X], implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[X])Array[X]
```

I would have thought it simple to generate a ClassTag from a TypeTag, but I see no obvious way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ClassTag form TypeTag, or both at same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321/how-to-get-classtag-form-typetag-or-both-at-same-time)

Answer (score 8):

I'd love to see a simpler solution, but here is what I came up with :

```
def fun[X:TypeTag]: Array[X] = {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  implicit val xClassTag = ClassTag[X]( mirror.runtimeClass( typeTag[X].tpe ) )
  Array.ofDim[X](10)
}
```

You'll want to make sure though that you really need to pass a `TypeTag` in the first place. Can't you pass a `ClassTag` instead (as in `def fun[X: ClassTag]`) ?

Comment: The problem really is cosmetic, I need a TypeTag within the scope of a function, but ClassTag at a call site within that function, and would rather not have extra type noise of requiring a ClassTag implicit all the way up the call chain.