# How to get ClassTag form TypeTag, or both at same time?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10, context-bound

I have some code like this:

```
class ReflectiveJsonFormat[T:TypeTag] extends JsonFormat[T] {
  def write(x: T) : JsValue = {
   val t = typeOf[T]
   val getters = t.declarations.filter { s => s.isMethod && s.asMethod.isGetter }
   val mirror = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
   val instanceMiror = mirror.reflect(x)
  }
}
```

That last line fails with:

> No ClassTag available for T

I thought `TypeTag` was more info than a `ClassTag`? Can I get the `ClassTag` from the `TypeTag`? If not, is there some syntax for saying that `T` has two context bounds -- both `TypeTag` and `ClassTag`? Or, how would you otherwise fix this code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well scala does support multiple context bounds if that is what you are after:

```
class ReflectiveJsonFormat[T:TypeTag:ClassTag]
```

Comment: I definitely prefer @gourlaysama's answer over this one. Asking for both is redundant since `TypeTag` is effectively a superset of `ClassTag` at least the way I think of it. As @gourlaysama's answer illustrates, ClassTag is really a wrapper around `java.lang.Class`, and from TypeTag you can get the appropriate Class instance.

Comment: For what is worth I entirely agree, but OP said "or both at the same time", which is actually easier to achieve (redundancy notwistanding), as my answer shows.

Answer (score 38):

The library doesn't provide a built-in method that directly converts a `TypeTag` to a `ClassTag`, but you can write one:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.ClassTag

def typeToClassTag[T: TypeTag]: ClassTag[T] = {
  ClassTag[T]( typeTag[T].mirror.runtimeClass( typeTag[T].tpe ) )
}
```

Then in your method just add before the implicit `ClassTag` is needed:

```
implicit val c = typeToClassTag[T]
```

Comment: Thanks, you both answered my 2-part question. I accepted the other one because in this case that's what I used.

Comment: Is it possible to get the typeTag from a classTag?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Generally no because ClassTag persists less compile-time info for runtime than TypeTag https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre More precisely, we can get `TypeTag` from `ClassTag` but it will persist less compile-time information than `TypeTag` originally https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/IT9OWEZfTiag0XJ1YhvNlw/4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502964/invoke-a-template-scala-function-with-a-type-stored-as-wild-card-classtag