# Scala: Using TypeTag in a method

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I am trying to write a method like this:

```
def foo[T:TypeTag](value: Int):String = {
  (/* do something */).mapTo[T].map(_.toJson)
}
```

where `mapTo` has the signature:

```
def mapTo[S](implicit tag: ClassTag[S]): Future[S] = { ... }
```

using `org.scala-lang.scala-reflect` to be able to do something like:

`foo[String](1)`, `foo[List[Double]](10)` and so on.

I tried to write it in different ways, but I got different compile errors.
Is there any way to make something like that to work?

```
Error:(26, 45) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for T
    (/* do something */).mapTo[T].map(_.toJson)
                                            ^
Error:(26, 45) not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[T])spray.json.JsValue.
Unspecified value parameter writer.
    (/* do something */).mapTo[T].map(_.toJson)
                                        ^
```

This link [How to get ClassTag form TypeTag, or both at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321) not clarify what I am after to. It looks like trying to "filter" some information about some class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ClassTag form TypeTag, or both at same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321/how-to-get-classtag-form-typetag-or-both-at-same-time)

Comment: I am not able to get an answer from what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the errors: `mapTo` works. It's `toJson` which doesn't, and it shouldn't: you can't convert any `T` with a `TypeTag` to JSON. Just require that `T` must have a `JsonWriter` as well: `def foo[T: TypeTag: JsonWriter](value: Int) = ...`. You'll also get a `Future[String]`, not a `String`.

Comment: thank you. Your suggestion worked! This is the final signature needed: `foo[T:TypeTag:JsonWriter](value: Int)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): StandardRoute`

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is a `ClassTag` then why not change the method of `foo` to have the `ClassTag`? Like so:

```
def foo[T](value: Int)(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): String ={ ...
```

That would seem to satisfy your basic need of declaring that there exists a `ClassTag` in implicit scope.

**Edit**:

What you're showing has nothing to do with `ClassTag` and everything to do with the fact that it's missing the implicits for a `JsonWriter` or a `JsonFormat`. You're probably missing an import to bring those into scope.

Comment: I have already tried it, but what do I pass in `bar[T]`? The compile problem is in `bar`.

Comment: @Randomize so you're saying that `val yo = something.bar[T]` doesn't work?