# Pass class type to a function in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have a function that has this signature;

```
def process[E: TypeTag : ClassTag](id: Int): E = {
```

Normally I would call it like this:

```
process[Item](1)
```

I need to call it from the place where the type of the item is stored in a variable.

```
tt.tpe.members.collect {
  case m if m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isCaseAccessor => m.asMethod
} foreach { member => {
  // member is a MethodSymbol that can be used to get a type
  // how to call process[??](id) from here?
```

I assume that I have to use reflect or returnType, but how can I pass the generic type?

Comment: Why do you think `member` is "a type"? It's a `MethodSymbol`

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I assume that there is a way to use it here anyway. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `typeTag` and `classTag` to the method explicitly, it will infer the type parameter from that:

```
process(id)(typeTag, classTag)
```

To figure out how to get `TypeTag` from `Type`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887386/get-a-typetag-from-a-type), and to get `ClassTag` from `TypeTag`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321/how-to-get-classtag-form-typetag-or-both-at-same-time).
To get `Type` from `member`, use `member.returnType`