# get java class for type tag of Scala case class

Tags: java, scala, reflection, types, typesafe-config

Using the type safe configuration and `configs` (`"com.github.kxbmap" %% "configs" % "0.4.4",`) library

```
def loadConfiguration[T <: Product: TypeTag]: T = {
    import configs.syntax._
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load
    conf.get[MyCaseClass]
```

should load the config, but fails as `T is not a class`.
How can I actually transform `T` to fit for `configs` as a java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I'd suggest simply replacing `TypeTag` with `ClassTag` since you aren't using the `TypeTag`. And if you were, you could combine them: `T <: Product : TypeTag : ClassTag]` or use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18730004/9204</s>

From the question I assumed "configs" could work given a Java `Class` object (or a `ClassTag` wrapping one). But after checking the documentation I see that it doesn't, so the above isn't relevant.

Instead you should use

```
def loadConfiguration[T : Configs]: T = ...
```

Comment: I tried that already, but get `T is not a class
[error]     conf.get[T]`

Comment: Fixed the answer.