# No TypeTag available for case class Type

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I want to generate a method which will convert an `Object` into a `Map[String, _]`, and later back from `Map[String, _]` to `Object`.

I generate the initial object as follows:

```
  case class Name (firstName : String, lastName : String)
  case class Documents (idx: String, name: Name, code: String)

  val mName1 = Name("Roger", "Rabbit")
  val myDoc = Documents("12", mName1, "ABCD")
```

Then following method converts a given `Map[String, _]` into an `Object`:

```
def fromMap[T : TypeTag: ClassTag ](m: Map[String,_]) = {
    val rm = runtimeMirror(classTag[T].runtimeClass.getClassLoader)
    val classTest = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
    val classMirror = rm.reflectClass(classTest)
    val constructor = typeOf[T].decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructor)

    val constructorArgs = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map( (param: Symbol) => {
      val paramName = param.name.toString
      if(param.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Option[Any]])
        m.get(paramName)
      else
        m.get(paramName).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is missing required parameter named " + paramName))
    })

    constructorMirror(constructorArgs:_*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

And inside the following method I convert the initial `Object` into a `Map[String, _]`, and back to `Object` (by invoking the method above):

```
def fromMapToObject(input: Any) : Unit= {

    println("input: "+input)

    //Converting an Object into a Map
    val r = currentMirror.reflect(input)
    val docAsMapValues = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
      .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
      .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.get)
      .toMap

    println("intermediate: "+docAsMapValues)


    val obj = fromMap[Documents](docAsMapValues)
    println("output: "+obj)

  }
```

So if I call:

```
 fromMapToObject(myDoc)
```

Input and output will match.

**Problem**, trying to go a step further, I want now to do the same with the field `name`, which is of type `Name`. But I want this step to be generic, in the sense that without knowing what is the type of the field `name`, I could convert it into a `Map[String, _]`, and from `Map[String, _]` back to `Object`.

So what I will do now in fromMapToObject is:

1. Extract from the input a `Map[String, _]`
2. Extract from the input a `Map[String, Types]`
3. Convert the value of the field `name` from `Name` into a `Map[String, _]`
4. Revert the 3rd step to get back an Object of type `Name`

This is how I am trying to approach this new scenario:

```
def fromMapToObject[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](input: Any) : Unit = {

    println("input: "+input)

    //Converting an Object into a Map
    val r = currentMirror.reflect(input)
    val docAsMapValues = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
      .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
      .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.get)
      .toMap

    val docAsMapTypes = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
      .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
      .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.symbol.typeSignature)
      .toMap

    // Here I extract from the map the value and type of the attribute name 
    val nameType = docAsMapValues("name")
    val nameValue =  docAsMapValues("name")

    // Converting Name into a map
    val r2 = currentMirror.reflect(nameValue)
    val nameAsMapValues = r2.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
      .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r2.reflectField(s)}
      .map(r2 => r2.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r2.get)
      .toMap

    type nameT = nameType.type
    val obj = fromMap[nameT](nameAsMapValues)

}
```

But I am getting the following error when compiling in Intellij:

```
Error:(111, 29) No TypeTag available for nameT
    val obj = fromMap[nameT](nameAsMapValues)
```

I would like to know how could I convert that `runtime.universe.Type` which is returned from `r.symbol.typeSignature` into a `TypeTag : ClassTag`

Comment: This sound like something **Shapeless** could resolve _(however I really do not know too much about Shapeless to be sure)_. Also, `Map[String, _]` looks petty similar to a **JSON** or a **HOCON**, had you tried searching for libraries that already do the job? Like **Circe** or **Spary**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, I will take a look to the libraries you mention.

Comment: Circe actually uses shapeless for it's auto derivation, so you're definitely on the right track! I don't have time to go through everything enough, so I'm not entirely certain what your intention for this is, but I'd recommend looking at Typeclasses and possible Shapeless. Can you add a motivating example, how you want your final usage of this function to look were it all working correctly?

Comment: @Ethan So the motivation is basically this. I get an Object, I dont know anything about the structure of the object (don't know the name of the attributes, it's types, if they are nested...). But they will give me one path to one or several attributes which I need to modify AND also the path to reach that attribute. For example: Change to uppercase Documents.name.firstName. So I need to access attributes in an Object having this attribute as a variable (that is why I converted into map), then once I apply the opperations on the target I should get back an Object.

Comment: When you say you have an Object, do you mean a `java.lang.Object` or something else like some sort of Json Object?

Comment: @Ethan it is a json stored in hbase which I read and store in an instance of a case class

Comment: So when you say you have an Object, do you mean you actually have a case class, a pile of JSON, or a java.lang.Object?

Comment: Do you know all of your data in this example will be a `Document`?

Comment: Is a `Map[Symbol,_]` an acceptable `Map` form for you? If you absolutely need a `Map[String,_]` it's possible, but will just require a bit of extra work.

Comment: @Ethan Replying to your questions: 1- I have a case class. 2- No, that is why I try to go to generics. We have lot's of different case classes, and this case classes may vary in the future, so I was targeting something generic, so I wanted to develop something which doest require to hardcode anything related with case clases. 3- I was using Map[String,_] because the String will be the name of the attribute in the case class, and the value could any type: String, Float, Documents...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution. Since I wasn't able to get `classTag` and `typeTag` I modified the function toMap as follow:

```
def fromMap2[T : ClassTag ](m: Map[String,_], mSymbol: Symbol, mType :Type): Any = {
    val rm = runtimeMirror(classTag[T].runtimeClass.getClassLoader)
    val classTest = mSymbol.asClass
    val classMirror = rm.reflectClass(classTest)
    val constructor = mType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructor)

    val constructorArgs = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map( (param: Symbol) => {
      val paramName = param.name.toString
      if(param.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Option[Any]])
        m.get(paramName)
      else
        m.get(paramName).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is missing required parameter named " + paramName))
    })

    constructorMirror(constructorArgs:_*).asInstanceOf[T]

  }
```

So now I need to pass the Type and Symbol of T. I can get these two values like follow:

```
//Converting an Object into a Map
val r = currentMirror.reflect(input)
val mapValues = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
  .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
  .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.get)
  .toMap

val mapTypes = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
  .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
  .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.symbol.typeSignature)
  .toMap

val mapTypesSymbols = r.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
  .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r.reflectField(s)}
  .map(r => r.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r.symbol.typeSignature.typeSymbol)
  .toMap

val nameType = mapTypes("name")
val nameTypeSymbols =  mapTypesSymbols("name")
val nameValue =  mapValues("name")

// Converting Name into a map
    val r2 = currentMirror.reflect(nameValue)
    val nameAsMapValues = r2.symbol.typeSignature.members.toStream
      .collect{case s : TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => r2.reflectField(s)}
      .map(r2 => r2.symbol.name.toString.trim -> r2.get)
      .toMap

type nameT = nameType.type

val obj = fromMap2[nameT](nameAsMapValues, nameTypeSymbols, nameType)
```

Even if this works, I believe it is very anti pattern. So I will leave the question open in case someone could point out ways to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely certain that I'm interpreting your question correctly, but from what I understand this can be solved pretty nicely and type safely via shapeless. To start with, you want to convert your `Document` to a `Map`. `shapeless` can do this out of the box for you with one of the Typeclasses in the `ops` folder. If we bundle that up into a function, with some machinery to pull everything together, we get something like:

```
import shapeless._

def ObjectToMap[A, Repr <: HList](obj: A)(
  implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A,Repr], //Convert to generic representation
  toMap: ops.record.ToMap[Repr] //Convert generic representation to Map[Symbol,_]
) = toMap(gen.to(obj))
```

which outputs

```
val m = ObjectToMap(myDoc)
println(m) //Map('code -> ABCD, 'name -> Name(Roger,Rabbit), 'idx -> 12)
```

Going the other direction is a little bit more complicated. There exists a `ops.maps.FromMap` typeclass. However, we want to be able to specify the type parameter, and then let the compiler still verify that the generic representation is an `HList`, to match up with `FromMap`'s signature. Since dependent types don't work with other variables defined in the same parameter list, and we only get one implicit parameter list, we need to resort to a little bit of trickery to curry the type parameters:

```
trait MapToObject[A]{
  def from[Repr <: HList](m: Map[_,_])(
    implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A,Repr],
    fromMap: ops.maps.FromMap[Repr]
  ): Option[A] = fromMap(m).map(gen.from)
}

object MapToObject{
  def apply[A](
    implicit gen: LabelledGeneric[A]
  ): MapToObject[A] = new MapToObject[A]{}
}
```

When we run the output of the previous chunk through that we get:

```
val doc = MapToObject[Documents].from(m)
println(doc) //Some(Documents(12,Name(Roger,Rabbit),ABCD))
```

Comment: And thanks for the answer Ethan. I read about shapeless, but they asked me to solve it without using 3rd party libraries so we have more control on each of the steps. Here is my final solution https://github.com/ignacio-alorre/Scala/blob/master/Reflection/ObjectsAnonimizer.scala . However, please leave this answer since it can be really useful for other users which can use shapeless.

Comment: That decision seems a little bit insane, but given what you've got the reflection solution seems fine. You might want to look into macros to replace the reflection, it might (or might not) turn out a little bit cleaner in practice. Or you can always just use the relevant bits of the shapeless source code.

Answer (score 1):

`type nameT = nameType.type` is incorrect. `nameType.type` is (singleton) type of this specific variable `nameType` and you want type of `name` field. This accidentally worked because actually you don't use `T` in `fromMap2` (`runtimeMirror(classTag[T].runtimeClass.getClassLoader)` can be replaced with `currentMirror` there).

You wanted to call your original `fromMap` inside `fromMapToObject`. You know `universe.Type` of `name` and it's enough to find [`TypeTag`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27889140/5249621) and [`ClassTag`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18730004/5249621) implicit parameters for `fromMap`. 
But it's not enough to find `T`. The thing is that since you use runtime reflection you know `universe.Type` (and `TypeTag`, `ClassTag`) at runtime. But in order to call `fromMap` you need to know `T` at compile time. So one way is to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027852/5249621) compile-time reflection i.e. macros. Other way is to avoid `T` and use value parameters like you did.

[Case class to map in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226555/case-class-to-map-in-scala)

[Scala: convert map to case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684572/scala-convert-map-to-case-class)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I will modify my final solution based on your answer

Comment: Hi, in case I remove the T: ClassTag, at the end of the function I am using: constructorMirror(constructorArgs:_*).asInstanceOf[T]. How could I replace that as well?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Let method return `Any`, cast it at call site.

Comment: Ok thanks again. But how else could I get the classTag of nameType, without using type nameT = nameType.type. As I understand for your second part of the answer nameType is the universe.Type, but I can't find a way to get the classTag from that value without the type nameT = nameType.type